# HttpWebRequest/StreamWriter fails every 50th request

Tags: sockets, ssl, tcp, reset, streamwriter

I'm having a problem with a .NET client connecting to an apache server for XML requests. **Exactly** every 50th time XML is transferred the response seems to be lost.

Looking at a WireShark trace on the client I can see that every 50th time the apache server sends an encrypted alert followed by a FIN, ACK. The client responds with a RST which closes the socket, but then the client continues to try to use the socket, it sends SYN packets without any response. When this happens the response doesn't get back to the application layer on the client.

After the client times out and reconnects (renegotiates encryption) it works another 49 times and then fails again.

Just to add this same .NET client is in use on many other client machines without a problem.

I can't find anyone else having this issue. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer yourself?